# How to redirect /page to index using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

How do I redirect /pages and /pages/ to the index page? I want to keep allowing people to get to /pages/ID-of-the-page/. Any attempts I've tried have resulted in /pages/ID-of-the-page/ being sent to a 404-page.

Here are some bits of my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^pages/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ pages.php?id=$1&page_id=$2

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/404page.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +Indexes -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com/404page.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^pages/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ pages.php?id=$1&page_id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^pages/?$ / [L,R]
```